# Javascript - how to perform sequential execution after https get

Tags: javascript, https, sequential

I am having a headache learning about javascript sequential execution order and having this code case:

```
function funcA() {
    var sampleUrl = "https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming";

    https.get(sampleUrl, function (response) {
        console.log("http call");
    });
    console.log("funcA");
}

funcA();
console.log("funcB");
```

I exptected the output order would appeared sequentially like this

```
http call
funcA
funcB
```

But the output appeared as follows

```
funcA
funcB
http call
```

meaning the output for `https.get` got delayed even until the printing of `funcB`.

Is there anyway to make the code output as expected but still hold the structure? I did googling and found some articles talking about `async`, `promise`, etc. but really had no idea to intergrate, so very appreciate to learn from your experience.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you're not groking here is Asycnronous exexcution. `https.get` is an async call, which traditionally takes a callback and calls the callback function after the `get` is completed. Modern asynchronous javascript involves promises and `Async` functions instead, which are a bit easier to code around usually than callbacks

Comment: You have to learn more about promises and async code. Async code is executed after sync code, so you always have to wait for the async code to finish (using async/await sugar syntaxis or the chainable function 'then'). Check this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing

Comment: @TKoL, Juan Castillo Thank you for your resoures! I will check and learn about those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `funcA` in a promise and resolve the callback.

```
function funcA() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // Start of your code
        var sampleUrl = "https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming";
        https.get(sampleUrl, function (response) {
            console.log("http call");
            // Resolve your response
            resolve(response)
        });
        // End of your code
    })
}

function funcB() { console.log('funcB') }
async function funcC() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => { console.log('funcC'); resolve() })
}
```

Then you can just use it as you would any Asynchronous method.

```
(async function init() {
    const jokeResponse = await funcA(); // Await your http.get
    funcB();       // Non-async method
    await funcC(); // Maybe another async method
})()
```

Your output would be:

```
http call
funcB
funcC
```

As a side note, you can just use the `fetch` method for simple `GET` requests. All modern browsers support `fetch` and it was built to replace `http.X` methods when the promise wrapper technique shown above became the standard "good way to do it".

```
const joke = await fetch("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming").then(res => res.json())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Btw I am currious if `fetch` the most common way to perform request nowadays or are there any others approach?

Comment: @JohnPham async javascript like `Promise` and `fetch` are the standard nowadays. Working with promises is a much cleaner way to wrangle otherwise dis-jointed asynchronous runtime code.